# What does CPLD mean in aviation in general and on this altitude alerter?

Tags: avionics, flight-instruments, altimeter

I saw the shortcut `CPLD` on this altitude alerter from a Cessna 210, and could not work out what it could possibly mean:

[image: Altitude alerter]

What does it mean on this altitude alerter, and if `CPLD` is also used elsewhere in aviation, what does stand for there ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The unit in the image is a Cessna AA-801A altitude alerter.

> CPLD Green Lamp:

> Lights when airplane reaches selected altitude and Integrated Flight Control System altitude hold mode is automatically engaged

CPLD would be short for coupled, indicating a system is linked to the autopilot.

You can see this and read more in [this C210 POH](https://usermanual.wiki/Document/Cessna210T210N1982POHscanned.4031269411/view), page 559 in the pdf (Supplement 47, page 4).

[image]

Comment: Ahh … Maybe I should read both the P210N and the T210N POH in the future - there seems to be a lot of information in the latter that isn't in the former. Thank you very much ! +1